# Retrieve attachments from EWS at once using EWS Managed API 2.0

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS in order to retrieve emails, but when I want to retrieve the attachments I have to call the following function for each:

```
fileAttachment.Load();
```

Everytime I do that, it goes to the server. Is it possible to retrieve all the attachments at once? Also, is it possible to retrieve all the attachments for several mail items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExchangeService object has a GetAttachments method which basically allows you to do a batch GetAttachment request. So if you want to load the attachments on several messages at once you need to do something like (first call loadpropertiesforitems which does a batch GetItem to get the AttachmentIds)

```
        FindItemsResults<Item> fItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,new ItemView(10));
        PropertySet psSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(fItems.Items, psSet);
        List<Attachment> atAttachmentsList = new List<Attachment>();
        foreach(Item ibItem in fItems.Items){
            foreach(Attachment at in ibItem.Attachments){
                atAttachmentsList.Add(at);
            }
        }
        ServiceResponseCollection<GetAttachmentResponse> gaResponses = service.GetAttachments(atAttachmentsList.ToArray(), BodyType.HTML, null);
        foreach (GetAttachmentResponse gaResp in gaResponses)
        {
            if (gaResp.Result == ServiceResult.Success)
            {
                if (gaResp.Attachment is FileAttachment)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File Attachment");
                }
                if (gaResp.Attachment is ItemAttachment)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item Attachment");
                }
            }
        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I had to install 2.2 for this but I'll take it as an answer.